# Joomla Menu Module with a Menu Heading as the base item

Tags: module, menu

[image: Menu Heading not selectable]

I want to add a list of menu items, and I want it to dynamically populate.  I thought I could just use the menu module.  I want only the sub/child items from "preparations and repairs".

Because the menu is a type of "menu heading" I cannot choose it.  I don't want to make it any other type of menu item.  Does anyone know what code I would need to change for this?

Comment: Please specify the version where you experienced this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that was introduced to the latest Joomla! version.  It's been fixed in an update.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a reference link to the bug or next commit ...or something?  What version will have this bug squashed?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find it.  Someone told me it was a known issue and had been fixed.  I can't find the issue I created either.